# How can I assign click function to many buttons using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 29 buttons: todayResultsbutton0 .. todayResultsbutton28,
and 29 divs: todayResultsUrls0 .. todayResultsUrls28.
I also have a function toggleVisibility(divName) that hide/show the given div.
I am trying to use the following code:

```
for (var i=0;  i < 29; ++i) {
    var b = "#todayResultsbutton"+i;
    var d = "todayResultsUrls"+i;
    $(b).click(function(){toggleVisibility(d);});
}
```

I thought that this will cause each button click to show/hide the matching div but the actual result is that clicking on any button (0 .. 28) show/hide the last div - todayResultsUrls28.

Can someone tell me where am I wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a sample of HTML? This will help us know how to structure the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a class.

```
$(".myClass").click(function() {
  var d = $(this).attr("id").replace("button", "Urls");
  toggleVisibility(d);
});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem of calling `toggleVisibility(d)`

Comment: I fixed it up to suit your example. Just give all your buttons the same class and inside the click function replace the portion of the id that identifies it as a button as opposed to a url.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use a loop, you'd be better off using the selector to "find" your divs..

say you have something like:

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="test" text="test" />
</td><td><div id="myDiv"></div></td></tr></table>
```

You can find myDiv by :

```
$('#myButton').parent().find('#myDiv').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "startsWith" attribute selector with the id, then build the url from the id of the clicked item.

```
$('[id^=todayResultsbutton]').click( function() {
     var url = this.id.replace(/button/,'Urls');
     toggleVisibility(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> var d = "#todayResultsUrls"+i;

Instead of

> var d = "todayResultsUrls"+i;

Answer (score 0):

Toggle visibility by finding the relevent div usint the [event target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) rather than classes etc.

Assuming:

```
<div id='todayResultsUrls1'>
    <button id='todayResultsbutton'></button>
</div>
```

Using the event target you can get the button element and find the div you want to hide.

```
var parentDiv = $(e.target).parent();
toggleVisibility(parentDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('button[id^="todayResultsbutton"]').click(function() {
    var index = this.id.substring(18,this.id.length);
    toggleVisibility("todayResultsUrls"+index);
});
```

This will find all `<button>` tags with id's starting with `todayResultsbutton`. It will then get the ID for the clicked tag, remove the `todayResultsbutton` part of it to get the id and then call the `toggleVisibilty()` function.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qwhzy/).

**Edit**
Notes:

- Using `button` before the starts with selector (`[id^="todayResultsbutton"]`) speeds up the jQuery selector because it can use the native `getElementsByTagName` function to get all button tags and then only check those for the specific ID.
- `this.id` is used instead of jQuery's `$(this).attr('id')` because it's faster (doesn't require wrapping `this` or calling the extra function `attr()`) and shouldn't cause any cross-browser issues.